# query javascript object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a casperjs script which iterates over a list of pages and extracts data.
On the other hand I have a csv file with 2 fields 'ean' 'ref' which I parse with Papa.parse. The output is an object. I am looking for a solution to query an javascript object (the output from Papa.parse) for the 'ref' field and extract the 'ean'. I thought `.filter()` is what i was looking for but that can only search for a predefined value in the callback function.

```
function cd(element) {
  return element == '123';
}
var b = c.filter(cd);
```

The problem hear is 1. It returns an empty array and 2. even if it would work I need to change the value with every call since I want to find the ean value for any given ref.

```
function cd(element,ref) {
  return element == ref;
}
```

This is the data I need to search

```
"data": [
        {
            "ean": "654321",
            "ref": "123"
        },
        {
            "ean": "1234567",
            "ref": "124"
        }
]
```

I hope I made myself more clear. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but it doesn't sound like you have JSON at all. It would help if you provided some code and sample data to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Write some code to do it, if you have a problem, then you can post a question.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object".  JSON is a _serialisation format_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://lodash.com/docs#where

Does exactly what i want

```
var a = _.where(array,{'ref' : 'value i am looking for'});
```

result is an array from where I can extract the value of the ean field.